# create an array by drag and drop items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to create an app to visually order an array of items, let say this is the `referenceArray`:

```
const referenceArray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6", "item 17"];
```

Now let's say we want to reorder the above array to an array of array: (this is not intentional)

```
   result = [ ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"], ["item 4"], ["item 5", "item 6"], [ "item 17"] ]
```

I want to get the above result by drag and drop the visual representation of the `referenceArray` so that each column will be an array inside the main array and items in the column will be the elements in inside array...

So we give the `referenceArray` to the app, then we reorder the items by drag and dropping and finally we get the `result` array as reordered version of `referenceArray` which each column is a array inside the main array and each item in a column is an element of the inside array.

So for getting the above result we should drag and drop items like this:

[image]

So far I have this simple drag and drop using jQuery UI, but it's not what we want as you see:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();

  $("#btn").on("click", function () {
    const positions = [];
    $("#sortable li").each(function (index, element) {
      positions.push($(this).text())
    });
    console.log(positions)
  });

});
```

```css
#sortable {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

ul {
  columns: 5;
  -webkit-columns: 5;

}
#sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  cursor: move;
  font-size: 1vw;
  height: 18px;
  background: gainsboro;
}
#sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 


<h1>Sort listing using drag & drop</h1>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>

  <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 12</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 13</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 14</li>
</ul>

<p>Drag and drop list to reposition...</p>
<button id="btn">Get positions and save them into an array of arrays</button>
<div class="show"></div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To make this work as you require you would need to have 4 separate but connected `sortable()` lists, one per column. Then to generate the final array you need to get the values from each sortable and put them in a parent array.

Comment: I can't sort  the items with above code... cause if you remove an item from a column another one replace it ....

Comment: That's exactly my point.

Comment: I've tried with no luck... I think I need a hand to find a proper solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connectWith](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith) of jquery sortable to make relationship between other sortable elements.In below code , i have created separate `uls` and have use `connectWith: ".sortable"` to connect them with one another.

Then, onclick of button i have get the length of `.sortable` class depending on this i have use `each` to iterate through all `uls` and store them in array of array.

***Demo Code***

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable"//use this to connect with other uls
  });
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();

  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    const positions = [];
    var count = 0;
    //get length of all sortable class
    var length = $(".sortable").length;
    //chck if count is less then length
    while (count < length) {
    //create empty arry
      data = []
      //loop thorugh uls .. li 
      $("ul:eq(" + count + ") li").each(function(index, element) {
        data.push($(this).text())//push data in array
      });
      positions.push(data)//push datas in outer array
      count++;//increment
    }
    console.log(positions)

  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <h1>Sort listing using drag & drop</h1>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 10</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 12</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 13</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 14</li>
  </ul>

  <p>Drag and drop list to reposition...</p>
  <button id="btn">Get positions and save them into an array of arrays</button>
  <div class="show"></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's not working when I try to align them into horizontal columns...

Comment: Hi can you create demo code with  changes you have made in current code?

Comment: Hi Swati, I actually updated the issue (new issue with the current code) here please have a look: and I fixed the last issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265922/editable-content-does-not-select-by-cursor-or-double-click